# how to pass an empty pandas query

Tags: python, pandas

For improvement in a model I am passing several .query() to a pandas dataframe. In the for loop I would to have an empty query as well, but didnt find anything in documentation.
It should return the full dataframe.

I tried:

```
temp_df.query(None)
temp_df.query()
```

But this doesnt work. Other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What should an empty query return?

Comment: the full dataframe

Comment: Why don't you just return `temp_df` in that case?

Comment: +1 on this question.  A good scenario I routinely have is that i programmatically create queries as in `q = some_func(); view = temp_df.query(q)` and I'd like to have the "empty" query to return the full dataframe. A trivial solution would be to use something such as `if q is None: view = temp_df else view = temp_df.query(q)`. But I'd rather have not to. An empty query would be ideal for these cases.

Comment: Another way of putting this is to think of it as the equivalent of `WHERE 1 = 1` in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I could come up ATM, yet still not satisfactory:

```py
col = temp_df.columns[0]
temp_df.query(f"{col}.isnull() or {col}.notnull()")
```

Comment: it works :)  
I guess a more handy solution should me implemented by pandas developers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'index' keyword for this:

```
temp_df.query('index == index or index != index')
```

This will get you both null & non-null indices of the dataframe i.e. the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

if your DataFrame isn't MultiIndexed, you can use

```
df.query('tuple()')
```

Comment: I'm finding that this fails for recent pandas versions (e.g. pandas 2.0)

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean array that's the same length as your DataFrame:

```py
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

In [3]: trivially_true = np.repeat(True, len(df))

In [4]: trivially_false = np.repeat(False, len(df))

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
    A   B   C   D
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15

In [6]: df.query('@trivially_true')
Out[6]: 
    A   B   C   D
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15

In [7]: df.query('@trivially_false')
Out[7]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D]
Index: []
```